# Unityscript - how to best set a 5 second delay on an action that takes 5 seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Every time I run this section of code and press the "d" key, Unity will crash. This leads me to believe that there is a logic error but I have no idea what is going wrong.

```
 private var    delayAmount         = 5.0;
 private var    timeDelay           = 0.0;
 private var    abilityEnd          = 0.0;
 public var     abilityDuration     = 5.0;
 public var     speed               = 2.0;

 function Update()
 {  
    if (Input.GetKey ("d") && Time.time > timeDelay)
    {   
        abilityEnd = Time.time + abilityDuration;
        while(abilityEnd > Time.time)
        {
           transform.Translate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        timeDelay = Time.time + delayAmount;     
    }
 }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: don't really understand what you are trying to do here, but in general the best way to add a delay would be to use coroutines and yield. You can take a look here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement instead of the while loop because the loop doesn't break and unity overloads and crashes (don't quote me I'm no expert that's just my explanation).

Comment: I assume it did work but the problem is bigger so it did not entirely fix  the problem for the OP (hence the unjustified downvote you first receive).

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that when it enters the while stays there in an infinite loop because Time.time cannot change! You have simply blocked the engine itself by entering while that relays on a value that cannot possibly be updated.

You have to change your approach by allowing the engine to get out of the Update method. The common way to deal with these scenarios is to use a lot of co-routines and execution semaphores.